# preg_replace(): in laravel and angular

Tags: json, angularjs, laravel

am using $http service in angular to obtain data from a database by the help of a restful api. The data is feed into a dropdown but when the data is later posted i get "preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array" error.

here is the piece of the code.

this is the service

```js
//this is the service in the controller




$http.get('/api/payment')
        .then(function(res){
           
            $scope.payment = res.data;
            
  
  //this post the data to the database
  
   save : function(payment_post) {
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/api/payment',
                headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                data: $.param(payment_post)
            });
        },
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
            <label>payment mode </label>

            <select class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="payment_post.name" ng-options="payment.name for payment in payment"></select>

            </div>
```

$http.get('/api/payment')
        .then(function(res){

```
        $scope.payment = res.data;
        });
```

thank you in advance

have manage to pin point the problem that am facing. Angular is passing the data as required but laravel is not saving it and the big problem lies in the  controller at the method  which  the data is suppose to be stored.

//this is the method

```
        public function store()
    {
     //test if data is passed to laravel from angular js.
/*
if (Input::has('name'))
        {
            return 'hello';
        }
*/
 $agent = new Agent();
 $agent->fname = Input::get('fname');
 $agent->lname = Input::get('lname');
 $agent->mname = Input::get('mname');
 $agent->id_number = Input::get('id_number');
 $agent->name = Input::get('name');
 $agent->gender = Input::get('gender');
 $agent->username = Input::get('username');
 $agent->save();
   // $agent->push();
}
```

//this is the model

```
    <?php
class Agent extends \Eloquent {
protected $table = "agent";
protected $fillable = [
  "id",
  "fname",
  "mname",
  "lname",
  "username",
  "id_number",
  "name",
  "gender",
  "created_at",
  "updated_at"
 ];
}
```

i know i must be missing something out can anyone point it out please for me.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle for your problem?

Comment: thank you for your respond am not very sure if it will come clearly feel free to ask anything and am still a newbie so i might not be getting something clearly [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bonche/wvzsjgw9/1/)

Comment: can you provide code for `/api/payment`?

Comment: it actually a resourceful route, in the backed which have used laravel to build, the way movement goes from route to controller, the model and finally gives a json response of the data in the db have added the response of the api in the jsfiddle

Comment: your problem is a server error message that you receive in the handler, so for solving you need see your server code for this route

Comment: so you need route and controller

Answer (score 0):

i have solved it after going over angularjs documentation thoroughly opened up my mind that the data that is feed to the drop down is in json format, not as an a array as i was thinking that is way laravel why not able to process the data passed to it to be saved. angular have a diffrent approach to ng-options directive.

here is the way the select should be.

```
  <select
  ng-model="payment_post.name"
  ng-options="value.name as value.name group by value.middle_name for value in payments">
     </select>
```